# Microsoft Teams provisions using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to provision the Microsoft Teams using PowerShell scripts.

Is there any way that we can do that.

If yes please provide the sample scripts or supporting articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `New-PnPTeamsTeam` command to create a new Team.

To use that, you can do that as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All"
```

and then

```
New-PnPTeamsTeam -DisplayName "<Your-team-name>"
```

Reference - [New-PnPTeamsTeam](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpteamsteam?view=sharepoint-ps)

If you want to add additional parameters like owner, team settings etc. just follow the link above. You need to be a Global admin or use an account with similarly high permissions to execute this command as it creates a SharePoint team site, Office 365 group and Team ofcourse.